# Apache2: Environment variables for user http

Tags: apache, http, environment

Is it possible for the apache2 user, http, to have environment variables like normal users do? How would I go about setting those up, if possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Your question is not clear about how you want to use the environment variables.*

For consideration: if in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, you put

```
SetEnv MYVAR 10
```

then that environment variable should be available in your scripting language (PHP for example).  In PHP, it can be accessed by `$_SERVER['MYVAR']`

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your `http` user has a login shell, which most don't, you could put it in there.  But that's still probably not going to do what you really want.  I usually accomplish what you're trying to do by putting the environment variables in `/etc/init.d/httpd`.